# How to utilise the space below a navlistPanel in shiny?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I'm looking at how I can utilise the space below a `navlistPanel()`.

Dummy code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <-  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Navlist panel example"),
    
    navlistPanel(
      "Header",
      tabPanel("First",
               h3("This is the first panel")),
      tabPanel("Second",
               h3("This is the second panel")),
      tabPanel("Third",
               h3("This is the third panel"))
    )
  )
    
server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Would produce something like below. I want to be able to insert text or other features in the highlighted area in red. I suppose this question could also apply if `navlistPanel()` was `sidebarPanel()`, but I know it's possible to be able to put more things inside the actual sidebar panel itself, compared to the `navlistPanel()` which only takes `tabPanel()`s or plain text elements.

[image]
**Edit:**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Navlist panel example"),
  div(navlistPanel(
    "Header",
    tabPanel("First",
             h3("This is the first panel"),
             plotOutput("myPlot")),
    tabPanel("Second",
             h3("This is the second panel")),
    tabPanel("Third",
             h3("This is the third panel"))
  ), 
  column(4, "foobarbaz"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot(plot(1:10))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can simply place the additional content outside of the `navlistPanel` call or wrap it in a div-tag:
library(shiny)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Navlist panel example"),
  navlistPanel(
    "Header",
    tabPanel("First",
             h3("This is the first panel")),
    tabPanel("Second",
             h3("This is the second panel")),
    tabPanel("Third",
             h3("This is the third panel"))
  ), 
  column(4, plotOutput("myPlot"))
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot(plot(1:10))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

# div-tag -----------------------------------------------------------------

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Navlist panel example"),
  div(navlistPanel(
    "Header",
    tabPanel("First",
             h3("This is the first panel")),
    tabPanel("Second",
             h3("This is the second panel")),
    tabPanel("Third",
             h3("This is the third panel"))
  ), 
  column(4, plotOutput("myPlot")))
  )


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot(plot(1:10))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

---

**After @Nautica's edit:**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Navlist panel example"),
  navlistPanel(
    "Header",
    tabPanel("First",
             h3("This is the first panel"),
             plotOutput("myPlot")),
    tabPanel("Second",
             h3("This is the second panel")),
    tabPanel("Third",
             h3("This is the third panel"))
  ), 
  column(4, "foobarbaz", style = "margin-top: -220px;")
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot(plot(1:10))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: If there is a big output in the tabPanel this pushes what I want below the `navlistPanel()` quite far down. Is there any way to fix this? Attached code explaining what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: Please see my edit - not very elegant but currently the only solution I was able to come up with.